# Can I make kdenlive use a different file manager

Tags: kdenlive

I run Ubuntu MATE 16.04, have installed the latest kdenlive from the ppa. I also installed "breeze" from the Ubuntu repo in order to get the icons and themes for kdenlive.

Now, kdelnlive uses the KDE file manager (Dolphin ?) but I want it to just use Caja.

Is it possible ? Can I configure it somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me... after searching DuckDuckGo:

#### Solution 1: The hard way:

If you're using the MATE desktop...

```
sudo apt -y install qt5ct
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct && kdenlive
```

Then edit your menu entry: **Menu > Sound and Video >** *[right click]* **Kdenlive**, then select **Edit Properties** and then in the **Command** field, replace `kdenlive %U` with `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct && kdenlive %U`

and for good measure, edit the same `/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kdenlive.desktop` (as root, like with the command `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/org.kde.kdenlive.desktop`) file, replacing

```
Exec=kdenlive %U
```

with

```
Exec=export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct && kdenlive %U
```

Save, quit the editor (nano, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and you won't (hopefully, *fingers crossed*) have a problem again.

#### Solution 2: Much easier:

[Download the AppImage of Kdenlive from kdenlive.org/download](http://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/kdenlive-18.04.1-x86_64.AppImage)

make it executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/your/download/kdenlive-18.04.1-x86_64.AppImage`) and then double-click it.

This actually is *much* easier and actually works. The Kdenlive site says that there is really no PPA for Ubuntu 18.04 and the AppImage is a breeze.

*(And it also works on other Linux distros. It's like the [PortableApps Platform](https://www.portableapps.com) in Windows.)*

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, ill try that tomorrow. I did try the app image but that gave me other issues, couldnt save theme and window settings for example.